# Using fgetc() for reading into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, fgetc

I wanna use `fgetc()` and put the input character in some array like `char *ch`. But apparently I can't put character (like 'M') in array and it has to be like "M", I mean with double quotation like a string.
This is my code, after getting user input I got `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
So I want to know if there is any way or trick that could do that.
Thanks in advance. :)

```
void main(){
    char *ch;
    int i = 0;
    while((ch[i] = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n'){
        i++;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: you have to allocate the ch array with malloc (if you are REALLY c) or new[]

Comment: Allocate memory for that array, either statically (`char ch[1000]`) or dynamically (using `malloc()`). Also, `main` returns `int`.

Comment: You need to give your ch pointer an initial size and dynamically updating it when it's full. Make sure you free all of them in properly when leaving scope (roughly your code context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can `realloc` for every character you read, that is a horribly inefficient way to allocate memory. A call to `malloc` is relatively expensive compared to an assignment of a character to an array element. It is far better to allocate some reasonably anticipated number of characters, read until your reach the limit, `realloc` at that point (updating the limit), and repeat until `EOF` (or whatever termination you choose).

The implementation is straight forward, but there are a couple of subtleties to note. When reallocating, always assign the result of `realloc` to a *temporary pointer* so you can *validate* that `realloc` succeeded before proceeding. Why? If `realloc` fails, it returns `NULL`. If you just blindly assign the result to your original array, and `realloc` fails, (1) you have just lost the pointer to your original array; and (2) you have just created a memory leak because the original block is left untouched -- it is not freed or moved.

With that in mind, you could read characters into an array, reallocating as needed, until `EOF` is reaches using something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NCHAR 1024  /* must be at least 1 */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int c;
    size_t n = 0, nchar = NCHAR;
    char *arr = malloc (sizeof *arr * nchar);
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!arr) { /* validate memory allocation succeeded */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((c = fgetc (fp)) != EOF) {  /* for each char in file */
        arr[n++] = c;       /* assign char to array */

        if (n == nchar) {   /* realloc preserving space for nul */
            void *tmp = realloc (arr, nchar + NCHAR);
            if (!tmp) {           /* validate realloc succeeded */
                fprintf (stderr, "realloc() error: memory exhausted.\n");
                break; /* break read loop, using existing 'arr' */
            }
            arr = tmp;     /* assign reallocated pointer to arr */
            nchar += NCHAR;        /* update the value of nchar */
        }
    }
    arr[n] = 0;                  /* affirmatively nul-terminate */

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);    /* close file if not stdin */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)   /* output arr */
    putchar (arr[i]);

    free (arr);   /* free allocated memory */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** above, on failure, the read loop is exited, preserving all characters in `arr` read up to that point in time.)

Lastly, in any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you haven't written beyond/outside your allocated block of memory, attempted to read or base a jump on an unintitialized value and finally to confirm that you have freed all the memory you have allocated. (For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice.)

A simple example (with `NCHAR` set to `2` to force multiple reallocations) would be:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/fgetc_realloc <../dat/captnjack.txt
==19710== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19710== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19710== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19710== Command: ./bin/fgetc_realloc
==19710==
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
==19710==
==19710== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19710==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19710==   total heap usage: 39 allocs, 39 frees, 1,560 bytes allocated
==19710==
==19710== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==19710==
==19710== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==19710== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

You want to find *All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible* and *ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts* (noting: on some OS, valgrind will not report `0` due to incomplete memory exclusion files)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually you answered a lots of my question, I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help. C is a very elegant language that provides more low level control over memory, hardware, etc.. than any other language your will find (other than assembly). With that much flexibility it takes a little longer to learn. One of the hurdles is learning dynamic memory allocation.  While this is a fairly simple bit of code, the allocate, track, reallocate, and free covers all of the basics of dynamic memory handling. So if you understand the what and why above, you have done well. Keep up the good work and good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 2):

In `char *ch`, ch is a pointer and it's value should be a valid memory location to store data in that memory location. Allocating memory dynamically to ch using `malloc()` or `realloc()` (use realloc if ch points to `NULL` initially) is necessary before using that pointer. Otherwise ch might contain garbage value and accessing that memory location results in `Segmentation fault`. I made changes to your program and it might help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char *ch = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    ch = realloc(ch, i+1);
    while((ch[i] = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n'){
        ch = realloc(ch, i+1);
        i++;
    }
    ch[i] = 0;
    puts(ch);
    free(ch);
    return 0;
}
```

As David C. Rankin said in the below comment:

> Calling realloc for every character read is horribly wasteful.
>   Allocate 128, 256, ... 1024 (or some reasonably expected number of
>   characters) read until the limit is reached and then realloc some sane
>   additional number of characters, then repeat...

Comment: Note: infinite loop with `while((ch[i] = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n')` should `fgetc()` return `EOF` for end-of-file.

Comment: Note: `main` is expected to return `int`, and in case you do that realloc in a function, you'll be leaking memory. Best practice would be to add a `free(ch)` before `return`.

Comment: Calling `realloc` for every character read is horribly wasteful. Allocate `128, 256, ... 1024` (or some reasonably expected number of characters) read until the limit is reached and then `realloc` some sane additional number of characters, then repeat...